# Kendo Grid filters closing in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am having a problem with Kendo UI Grids in IE8, and I have not seen any posts about this particular problem.

Our application uses several Kendo grids, most with multiple columns. In some columns of some of these grids, the filters only work once.

If you click the filter icon, enter in filter text and click "Filter" the column will filter correctly. However if you click the filter icon again, the filter menu opens and closes instantly, with no way to clear the filter.

Has anyone see the behavior of the filter menu opening closing instantly? This is only happening on Internet Explorer 8.

Other information:
I am using Kendo UI Complete v2012.1.515 with jQuery v1.7.2.
The dataSource for the grid uses the result of a Controller action from MVC2. The transport for the dataSource is as follows:

```
transport: 
{
   read: {
      url: '<%= Url.Action("GetAllItems","MyController") %>', 
            dataType: 'json', 
            type: 'POST'
          }
}
```

Comment: Not sure without more info. How is your schema defined? On an unrelated note, I'm curious why you perform a POST to GET data?